# Get subscription id from invoice.payment_failed webhook in Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

In my application I have customers which one can have multiple subscriptions. When some of the subscription payment will fail I send via stripe webhooks this params to my server:

```
{
  "created"=>1326853478,
  "livemode"=>false,
  "id"=>"evt_00000000000000",
  "type"=>"invoice.payment_failed",
  "object"=>"event",
  "request"=>nil,
  "pending_webhooks"=>1,
  "api_version"=>"2015-02-18",
  "data"=>{
    "object"=>{
      "date"=>1426238137,
      "id"=>"in_00000000000000",
      "period_start"=>1426232774,
      "period_end"=>1426238137,
      "lines"=>{
        "data"=>[
          {
            "id"=>"sub_5rZCR6ApQpG5fJ",
            "object"=>"line_item",
            "type"=>"subscription",
            "livemode"=>true,
            "amount"=>2500,
            "currency"=>"usd",
            "proration"=>false,
            "period"=>{
              "start"=>1428921062,
              "end"=>1431513062
            },
            "subscription"=>nil,
            "quantity"=>1,
            "plan"=>{
              "interval"=>"month",
              "name"=>"Monthly device subscription",
              "created"=>1426232489,
              "amount"=>2500,
              "currency"=>"usd",
              "id"=>"monthly-device",
              "object"=>"plan",
              "livemode"=>false,
              "interval_count"=>1,
              "trial_period_days"=>nil,
              "metadata"=>{

              },
              "statement_descriptor"=>nil
            },
            "description"=>nil,
            "metadata"=>{

            }
          }
        ],
        "total_count"=>1,
        "object"=>"list",
        "url"=>"/v1/invoices/in_15fotJEFda5OVrS251rpXd9l/lines"
      },
      "subtotal"=>2500,
      "total"=>2500,
      "customer"=>"cus_00000000000000",
      "object"=>"invoice",
      "attempted"=>true,
      "closed"=>false,
      "forgiven"=>false,
      "paid"=>false,
      "livemode"=>false,
      "attempt_count"=>1,
      "amount_due"=>2500,
      "currency"=>"usd",
      "starting_balance"=>0,
      "ending_balance"=>0,
      "next_payment_attempt"=>nil,
      "webhooks_delivered_at"=>1426238137,
      "charge"=>"ch_00000000000000",
      "discount"=>nil,
      "application_fee"=>nil,
      "subscription"=>"sub_00000000000000",
      "tax_percent"=>nil,
      "tax"=>nil,
      "metadata"=>{

      },
      "statement_descriptor"=>nil,
      "description"=>nil,
      "receipt_number"=>nil
    }
  },
  "webhook"=>{
    "created"=>1326853478,
    "livemode"=>false,
    "id"=>"evt_00000000000000",
    "type"=>"invoice.payment_failed",
    "object"=>"event",
    "request"=>nil,
    "pending_webhooks"=>1,
    "api_version"=>"2015-02-18",
    "data"=>{
      "object"=>{
        "date"=>1426238137,
        "id"=>"in_00000000000000",
        "period_start"=>1426232774,
        "period_end"=>1426238137,
        "lines"=>{
          "data"=>[
            {
              "id"=>"sub_5rZCR6ApQpG5fJ",
              "object"=>"line_item",
              "type"=>"subscription",
              "livemode"=>true,
              "amount"=>2500,
              "currency"=>"usd",
              "proration"=>false,
              "period"=>{
                "start"=>1428921062,
                "end"=>1431513062
              },
              "subscription"=>nil,
              "quantity"=>1,
              "plan"=>{
                "interval"=>"month",
                "name"=>"Monthly device subscription",
                "created"=>1426232489,
                "amount"=>2500,
                "currency"=>"usd",
                "id"=>"monthly-device",
                "object"=>"plan",
                "livemode"=>false,
                "interval_count"=>1,
                "trial_period_days"=>nil,
                "metadata"=>{

                },
                "statement_descriptor"=>nil
              },
              "description"=>nil,
              "metadata"=>{

              }
            }
          ],
          "total_count"=>1,
          "object"=>"list",
          "url"=>"/v1/invoices/in_15fotJEFda5OVrS251rpXd9l/lines"
        },
        "subtotal"=>2500,
        "total"=>2500,
        "customer"=>"cus_00000000000000",
        "object"=>"invoice",
        "attempted"=>true,
        "closed"=>false,
        "forgiven"=>false,
        "paid"=>false,
        "livemode"=>false,
        "attempt_count"=>1,
        "amount_due"=>2500,
        "currency"=>"usd",
        "starting_balance"=>0,
        "ending_balance"=>0,
        "next_payment_attempt"=>nil,
        "webhooks_delivered_at"=>1426238137,
        "charge"=>"ch_00000000000000",
        "discount"=>nil,
        "application_fee"=>nil,
        "subscription"=>"sub_00000000000000",
        "tax_percent"=>nil,
        "tax"=>nil,
        "metadata"=>{

        },
        "statement_descriptor"=>nil,
        "description"=>nil,
        "receipt_number"=>nil
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And now I want to get from this params stripe subscription_id. But I don't know which one is right because we have the following data in this param:

`"id"=>"sub_5rZCR6ApQpG5fJ"` - line 19 - Always stripe subscription start

with sub so maybe this is subscription_id?

`"subscription"=>"sub_00000000000000"` - line 77 - Maybe this one?

Please help I can't find any information about this in stripe docs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get the event `invoice.payment_failed` you can retrieve the corresponding subscription id in the `subscription` key in the `data` hash.

In your example it's `"subscription"=>"sub_00000000000000"` because you are using the "Send Test Webhook..." which sends fake data and not data based on your own account.

If you want to test with real data, the easiest solution is to create a subscription for a customer without a card. You'd use the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription) and set `trial_end` to a few minutes in the future. That way the first invoice for $0 would be charged successfully but the next one a few minutes later for the plan price would fail as expected.

Comment: When implementing stripe webhook in java, I am successful in getting the event object in JSON format. The problem is I am not able to get the details like the amount, subscription_id, attributes which are in nested JSON. Getting these values from the class object is also not available. Could you please tell me how to extract these values.

Comment: @viper please ask a separate question for this